# What is the difference between peer channel leave and peer channel unjoin in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to understand the difference between the peer channel leave command in Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.4 and the peer channel unjoin command in Fabric 2.4.7.

From what I understand, both commands are used to remove a peer from a channel and remove the channel's ledger data from the peer's local database. Is this correct, and if so, what are the main differences between the two commands?

I have read the documentation, but it's not clear to me how the two commands differ and which one should be used in different situations. Can someone provide more information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what documentation you are looking at but hyperledger fabric doesn't have a `peer channel leave` CLI command. The only way a peer can stop particpating in a channel is via the `peer node unjoin` CLI command.
Official documentation for the upcoming 2.5 release can be found at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/

Comment: Thank you. I think the document I'm looking at is wrong. Actually, I tried to **peer channel leave** in the 2.2.4 version CLI, but I confirmed that it was not provided.

Answer (score 1):

`peer channel leave` is an invalid command, if you want to leave a channel then in that case you can use `peer node unjoin` command which is available from v2.4.

> You can now unjoin a peer from a channel when the channel is no longer needed. All channel resources will be removed from the peer and the peer will no longer process blocks from the channel.

Command reference can be found here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/commands/peernode.html#peer-node-unjoin